# How can i use a function i defined in another file?

Tags: javascript, function, reference, src

I have a three js function defined in my utils.js file.

in this file i have exported the function remve.

I have an index file that i then want to use this function in. How can i do this.

Comment: Do you have a HTML file ? Or is index another js file ?

Comment: When you add `removeBySid()` to `utils.js` just load `utils.js` **before** index.js. You do not need the `export` directive.

Comment: index.html is a sample file. please see the updated question with images.

Comment: the export is required in utils.js for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 'util.js' file is not properly referenced. Can you add that file to 'js' directory and correctly add the reference like

```
<script src="js/util.js"></script>
```